# Python all combinations from parameterized list

Tags: python, math, combinations

Good day everyone, I need to get all possible combination from the list with parameters.

for example, we can have a list with parameters, where:

- the parameter has only value, in this case, this parameter will not be changed
- the parameter has a lower and high limit, in this case, the parameter will be changed from the lower limit to high limit wit some step

here is my a code

```
from typing import List

class Parameter:
  def __init__ (self, value = None, lowLimit = None, hightLimit = None, step = None):
    self.value = value
    self.lowLimit = lowLimit
    self.hightLimit = hightLimit
    self.step = step

data: List[Parameter]  = [Parameter(1), Parameter(2, 2, 3, 1), Parameter(3, 3, 4, 1)]

def recursion(array: List[Parameter], skip: int):
  for index, value in enumerate(array):
    if index < skip: continue
    if value.lowLimit is not None and value.hightLimit is not None:
      temp = [it.value for it in array]
      init = value.lowLimit

      while init <= value.hightLimit :
        temp[index] = init
        init += value.step
        yield temp

def combination(array: List[Parameter]):
  for index, value in enumerate(array):
    if value.lowLimit is None and value.hightLimit is None : continue
    for d in recursion(array, index):
      yield d


for d in combination(data):
  print(d)
```

and this what I would like to get:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 5]
[1, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 3]
```

but my code does not work, and I need some help to implement this task. Could someone help, please?

Comment: Should the last two be `[1,3,4]` and `[1,3,5]`?

Comment: yes, they should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I really understand what you are asking for, but I think you can convert your `Parameters` to `ranges` and then get the `itertools.product` of those:

```
import itertools
data = [Parameter(1), Parameter(2, 2, 3, 1), Parameter(3, 3, 5, 2)]
ranges = [[p.value] if p.lowLimit is None else
          range(p.lowLimit, p.hightLimit+1, p.step) for p in data]
print(ranges)
# [[1], range(2, 4), range(3, 6, 2)]
for d in itertools.product(*ranges):
    print(d)
# (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 3), (1, 3, 5)
```

(Note: Output differs as I slights changed the `data` to actually use a `step != 1`)